# When using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi for swagger how can you make enum return with their names? C#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger, openapi

We create lots of Azure functions and I know using Swashbuckle you can add ISchemaFilter to create x-enumNames for your enum.  I would ideally like to use Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi alone though to save having to add the additional http functions and startup configuration that swashbuckle requires.  This seem simple enough, but I was unable to find any way to do this at all using the Azure Open API